# List files on HTTP/FTP server in R

Tags: regex, r, html-parsing, text-parsing

I'm trying to get list of files on HTTP/FTP server from R!, so that in next step I will be able to download them (or select some of files which meet my criteria to download).

I know that it is possible to use external program in web browser (download manager) which will allow me to select files to download from current web page/ftp. However, I wish to have everything scripted, so that it will be easier for me to reproduce.

I thought about calling Python from R! (since it seems much easier), but I tried to do that entirely in R!

I wrote following lines

```
require("RCurl") 
result <- getURL("http://server",verbose=TRUE,ftp.use.epsv=TRUE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
```

Result variable is character type:

```
typeof(result)
[1] "character"
```

Sample content is as follows:

---

> Interesting file_20150629.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31  289K\nInteresting
>   file_20150630.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   293K\nInteresting
>   file_20150701.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   301K\nInteresting
>   file_20150702.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   304K\nInteresting
>   file_20150703.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   301K\nInteresting
>   file_20150704.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   300K\nInteresting
>   file_20150705.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   300K\nInteresting
>   file_20150706.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   305K\nInteresting
>   file_20150707.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   305K\nInteresting
>   file_20150708.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   301K\nInteresting
>   file_20150709.txt20 Aug-2015 09:31 
>   294K\n
>
> ---
>
> \n\n\n"

---

So now, I'm trying to parse result content:

```
myFiles <- strsplit(result,'<a[^>]* href=\\"([^"]*.txt)\\"')[[1]]
```

hoping that I will match txt file (since it's in brackets: ()). but it matches:

```
">Interesting file_20150706.txt</a></td><td align=\"right\">20 Aug-2015 09:31  </td><td align=\"right\">305K</td></tr>\n<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/apacheIcons/text.gif\" alt=\"[TXT]\"></td><td>
```

instead.

What is wrong (I tested my expression on https://regex101.com/) or (maybe this question is more appropriate) there is much easier way to obtain list of files with specific extension on the server in R! ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really shouldn't use regex on html.  The `XML` package makes this pretty simple.  We can use `getHTMLLinks()` to gather any links we want.

```
library(XML)
getHTMLLinks(result)
#  [1] "Interesting file_20150629.txt"   "Interesting file_20150630.txt"  
#  [3] "Interesting file_20150701.txt"   "Interesting file_20150702.txt"  
#  [5] "Interesting file_20150703.txt"   "Interesting file_20150704.txt"  
#  [7] "Interesting file_20150705.txt"   "Interesting file_20150706.txt"  
#  [9] "Interesting file_20150707.txt"   "Interesting file_20150708.txt"  
# [11] "Interesting file_20150709.txt"
```

That will get all `/@href` links contained in `//a`.  To grab only the ones that **contain** `.txt`, you can use a different XPath query from the default.

```
getHTMLLinks(result, xpQuery = "//a/@href[contains(., '.txt')]")
```

Or even more precisely, to get those files that **end** with `.txt`, you can do

```
getHTMLLinks(
    result,
    xpQuery = "//a/@href['.txt'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
)
```

Comment: Great response! I still don't know what was wrong in my regex, but your solution works perfectly!!!

Comment: Yeah, nice code. This helped me a lot. Especially last two sections.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative without loading additional libraries is to turn ftp.use.epsv=FALSE and crlf = TRUE. This will instruct libcurl to change \n's to \r\n's:

```
require("RCurl") 
result <- getURL("http://server",verbose=TRUE,ftp.use.epsv=FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE, crlf = TRUE)
```

Then extract the individual URLs to the files using paste and strsplit,

```
result2 <- paste("http://server", strsplit(result, "\r*\n")[[1]], sep = "")
```