# List XML files in web server directory and subdirectories

Tags: r, xml, http, https

I'm trying to get a list of all the XML documents in a web server directory (and all its subdirectories).

I've tried these examples:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213591/list-files-on-http-ftp-server-in-r):

```
library(XML)  
url <- "https://cmgds.marine.usgs.gov/metadata/pcmsc/"
getHTMLLinks(url)
```

Returns:  `character(0) Warning message: XML content does not seem to be XML`

[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930933/retrieve-the-list-of-files-from-a-url):

```
readHTMLTable(url)
```

Returns the same error.

I've tried other sites as well, like those included in the examples. I saw some SO questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584514/error-xml-content-does-not-seem-to-be-xml-r-3-1-0)) about this error saying to change `https` to `http`. When I do that I get `Error: failed to load external entity`.

Is there a way I can get a list of all the XML files at that URL and all the subdirectories using R?

Answer (score 2):

To get the raw html from the page:

```
require(rvest)

url <- "https://cmgds.marine.usgs.gov/metadata/pcmsc/"

html <- read_html(url)
```

Then, we'll get all the links using `html_nodes`. The names are truncated, so we need to get the `href` attribute rather than just using `html_table()`.

```
data <- html %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr('href')
```

Comment: Surrounding your code with some explanation would improve your answer.

Comment: This seems to truncate file names that are too long, i.e. the list that's returned is truncated as it appears in a web browser. Do you know if there's a way around that? Also, is it possible to get into the subdirectories, other than looping through them all with extra code?

Comment: @Bird See my update. For the sub-directories I'm not sure.